# Who introduced the terms "equivalence relation" and "equivalence class"?

Tags: reference-request, ho.history-overview, terminology, foundations

Consider that the question does not concern the origin of the ideas of equivalence relation and equivalence class. It exactly concerns **the origin of the terms** "equivalence relation" and "equivalence class". It seems that the terms weren't in use at least until 1903 where Russell writes:

> Peano has defined a process which he calls definition by abstraction,
>   of which, as he shows, frequent use is made in Mathematics. This
>   process is as follows: when there is any relation which is transitive,
>   symmetrical and (within its field) reflexive, then, if this relation
>   holds between u and v, we define a new entity Ø (u), which is to be
>   identical with Ø (v).
>
> Relations which possess these properties are an important kind, and
>   it is worthwhile to note that similarity is one of this kind of
>   relations.

**UPDATE**: Thanks to the suggestions given in the comments and a very informative answer of Francois Ziegler, suddenly the following piece from Russell's Introduction to Mathematical Philosophy  came into a new light:

> The question “what is a number?” is one which has been often asked,
>   but has only been correctly answered in our own time. The answer was
>   given by Frege in 1884, in his Grundlagen der Arithmetik. Although his
>   book is quite short, not difficult, and of the very highest
>   importance, it attracted almost no attention, and the definition of
>   number which it contains remained practically unknown until it was
>   rediscovered by the present author in 1901.

So, perhaps that was Frege himself who used the terms! Although, I couldn't find anything in Frege's writings yet. But now, considering Eugen Netto's paper (see Francois' update below) a very more important question now is: Is he indeed Russell who should be credited with rediscovering Frege in 1901?!

**PS.** I am well aware that asking a new question inside another question is not a good idea. However, up until this post I had the feeling that apart from the origin of the terms I know "everything" about the history of the notions of equivalence relation and equivalence class (part of which has been published [here](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10649-008-9173-x#)). But, this new information caught me by surprise, and I could not help myself to add the new question. You may just ignore it.

Comment: My guess (without any checking): Bourbaki I

Comment: @PeterMichor He (!) indeed defined "equivalence relation" and "equivalence class" in "Theory of sets". But, there is a big time gap between what I quoted from Russell and the Bourbaki's book. It is very strange that such an important notion remains unnamed for such a long time.

Comment: It certainly predates Bourbaki.  Birkhoff was using the term "equivalence relation" in 1934 (abstract number 323 in http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1934-40-11/S0002-9904-1934-05986-X/S0002-9904-1934-05986-X.pdf), and in a 1935 paper he mentions the 1927 book Höhere Algebra by Hasse (see the footnote on page 446 of http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~ralph/Classes/619/birkhoff1935.pdf).  Hasse uses the term Äquivalenzrelation also in a 1927 paper (Crelle, volume 157, page 120).  I assume this goes further back, but I don't know how far.

Comment: @HenryCohn That's great. The time gap is now only 24 years.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Von Neumann uses "equivalence class" in [*Zur Prüferschen Theorie der idealen Zahlen*, Acta Sci. Math. (Szeged) **2** (1926) 193-227](http://pub.acta.hu/acta/showCustomerVolume.action?id=5089&dataObjectType=volume), p. 197 (viewable after free registration):

> Wir nennen $R$ und $S$ *äquivalent*, in Zeichen: $R\sim S$, wenn (...)
>
> Satz 2. Es ist stets $R\sim R$. Aus $R\sim S$ folgt $S\sim R$. Aus $R\sim S$ und $S\sim T$ folgt $R\sim T$.
>
> (...)
>
> Infolge des Satzes 2. zerfällt die Menge der Folgen realer Zahlen in paarweise elementefremde Klassen untereinander äquivalenter Folgen.
>
> (...)
>
> Definition 4. Eine **Aequivalenzklasse**, die lauter Fundamentalfolgen enthält, nennen wir eine *ideale Zahl*.

This seems like an early example, in that he sees fit to add here the footnote: "We define the ideal number as the corresponding set of fundamental sequences, itself; naturally one could also regard it as an ideal element attached to this set."

I note also that Hasse's book *Höhere Algebra* (where Henry Cohn found the earliest occurrence of "equivalence relation" so far) appears to have a [1926 edition too](http://books.google.com/books?id=2UdtAAAAMAAJ&q=%C3%A4quivalenzrelation).

---

**Update 1:** One might also quote a paper by Eugen Netto, [*Über die arithmetisch-algebraischen Tendenzen Leopold Kronecker's*, in: Mathematical Papers read at the International Mathematical Congress (Chicago, 1893), Macmillan 1896, pp. 243-252](http://www.mathunion.org/ICM/ICM1893/), who writes:

> "Jede wissenschaftliche Forschung geht darauf aus, *Aequivalenzen* festzustellen und deren *Invarianten* zu ermitteln (...)."
>
> Jede Abstraction, z. B. die von gewissen Verschiedenheiten, welche eine Anzahl von Objecten darbietet, statuirt eine Aequivalenz; alle Objecte, die einander bis auf jene Verschiedenheiten gleichen, gehören zu einer **Aequivalenzclasse**, sind unter einander aequivalent, und der aus der Abstraction hervorgehende Begriff bildet die "Invariante der Aequivalenz."

---

**Update 2:** Finally(?) one should probably also quote Vol. 2 of Weber's [*Lehrbuch der Algebra* (1896)](http://archive.org/stream/lehrbuchderalgeb02weberich#page/n573). Literally he uses neither "equivalence relation" nor "equivalence class", but see how close he gets in §152 "Aequivalenz":

> 1. *Zwei ganze oder gebrochene Functionale $\varphi$, $\psi$ im Körper $\Omega$ heissen **äquivalent**, wenn (...)*
> 2. *Zwei Functionale, die mit einem dritten äquivalent sind, sind auch unter einander äquivalent.*
>
> Theilt man hiernach alle Functionale des Körpers $\Omega$ in ***Classen*** ein, indem man zwei Functionale in dieselbe oder in verschiedene Classen wirft, je nachdem sie äquivalent sind oder nicht, so ergiebt sich (...)

Same for Dedekind's [*Ueber die Theorie der algebraischen Zahlen* (1879)](http://archive.org/stream/vorlesungenberz02dedegoog#page/n559), §175:

> Wir wollen nun zwei Ideale $\mathfrak a$, $\mathfrak a'$ ***äquivalent*** nennen, wenn (...)
>
> Zugleich ergiebt sich hieraus, dass (...) je zwei Ideale $\mathfrak a'$, $\mathfrak a''$, die mit einem dritten Ideal $\mathfrak a$ äquivalent sind, stets auch miteinander äquivalent sein müssen. Auf diesem Satze beruht die Möglichkeit, alle Ideale in *Idealclassen* einzutheilen; (...) der Inbegriff $A$ *aller* mit $\mathfrak a$ äquivalenten Ideale $\mathfrak a$, $\mathfrak a'$, $\mathfrak a''$ (...) nennen wir eine *Idealclasse* oder kürzer eine ***Classe***

(Of course, calling *class* a family of objects related by some *equivalence* is a custom that can be traced to much older work — cf. Dirichlet [[1863, p. 172](http://archive.org/stream/vorlesungenberz03dedegoog#page/n191)] or Eisenstein [[1847, p. 118](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=GDZPPN002145928)] or Gauss [[1801, §223](http://archive.org/stream/werkecarlf01gausrich#page/n231)].)

Comment: How did you find that? Once upon a time, before the age of MO, I did a two years search and I failed. Shame on me :)

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=aequivalenzklasse -- Shame on *me* ;)

Comment: I wait a few days to see if there is an earlier date. If not, I "accept" your answer. Considering that you reduced the time suggested by Henry Cohn in a few minutes, I am sure a few days would be fair to history.

Comment: J. Hurwitz and J. König use "Äquivalenzbeziehung" in papers from 1902 and 1905 (http://www.google.com/search?q=äquivalenzbeziehung&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1800%2Ccd_max%3A1905&tbm=bks) but I'm not certain the meaning is quite the same as you want.

Comment: The meaning that I want is exactly the one we use today. It is for sure that I cannot read those papers. I now understand why a wise man once said "knowing three languages is better than two"!

Comment: I don't find the Hurwitz paper, but König seems to use the term for having the same cardinality.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Shall we credit König also for the term "equivalence class"? Or it is just "equivalence relation"? Could you give a reference for the exact paper of his that you saw the term? What is the date?

Comment: @Amir The term is "Äquivalenzbeziehung" and used in the 1905 paper "Zum Kontinuum-Problem" in the *Mathematische Annalen*. There are no equivalence classes and he only uses the term for "equal in cardinality".

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler Thanks very much for the time and effort you put on this question. It was indeed an amazing journey for me.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: 'Äquivalenz' or 'äquivalent' for same cardinality is already used by Cantor as well (not sure exactly when first, but likely 1870s already).

Comment: Regarding the Dedekind quote, there is an earlier (French) version in §28 of (http://www.numdam.org/item?id=BSMA_1877_2_1_1_207_1) (1877). Perhaps significantly, the Jahrbuch reviewer of that paper was Eugen Netto (http://www.emis.de/cgi-bin/JFM-item?09.0126.01).

Answer (score 1):

Re: the two questions in your **UPDATE**, I'd like to recommend the 2005 paper [*Frege's Natural Numbers: Motivations and Modifications*](http://www.faculty.ucr.edu/~reck/publications.html) by Erich Reck:

- Regarding other people's awareness of Frege's definition of number, Reck involves — as if by coincidence! — two of our previous protagonists, p. 276:

  > the Frege-Russell conception of numbers (...) seems to have been in the air already before Russell's writings. For example, the mathematician Heinrich Weber proposes essentially the same conception, independently of both Frege and Russell, in an [1888 letter to Richard Dedekind](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=PPN23569441X&PHYSID=PHYS_0493) (...)
- Regarding Frege's awareness of "equivalence relations", he raises (but leaves open) precisely that question in endnotes 5 and 41:

  > It would be interesting to know to what degree, and in what form exactly, Frege was also aware of equivalence class constructions in the algebra of his time (...) I am not aware of any historical account of the use of such methods in nineteenth-century mathematics, or even earlier; thus I am not sure how safe it is, in the end, to assume that Frege knew about them.

Comment: Your new answer encouraged me to add a follow up as an answer. MO, I am sorry, it wasn't fit as a comment :)

Answer (score 0):

This is to add something to **Francois' answer to the UPDATE**. This is from "Frege : philosophy of mathematics" by Dummett (1991), p. 50:

> One of the mental operations most frequently credited with creative
>   powers was that of abstracting from particular features of some object
>   or system of objects, that is, ceasing to take any account of them. It
>   was virtually an orthodoxy, subscribed to by many philosophers and
>   mathematicians…, that the mind could, by this means, create an object
>   or system of objects lacking the features abstracted from, but not
>   possessing any others in their place. It was to this operation that
>   Dedekind appealed in order to explain what the natural numbers are.
>   …Frege devoted a lengthy section of Grundlagen, §§29-44, to a detailed
>   and conclusive critique of this misbegotten theory; it was a bitter
>   disappointment to him that it had not the slightest effect.

I had never a chance to read Frege's Grundlagen. Worse, at the moment, I don't know how  Reck, Dummett and Russell views about Grundlagen may come together!

Comment: I think the critique/controversy here is between those (like Frege, Russell, or Weber in his letter) who would take the newly defined objects to *be the equivalence classes themselves*, and those (like Kummer, Peano, or allegedly Dedekind) who'd rather have them be "corresponding abstract entities", somehow created by the mind out of thin air. But my quote of Dedekind 1879, or his 1888 answer to Weber, show that he could also do without such extra entities (just like von Neumann in his 1926 footnote).